# how to insert edit data inside calendar control day render event asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i have the code below.when i add a data in particular day cell.the data inserts in another daycell.please help.what is the problem in my code.why sometimes the data is inserted properly nad sometimes it is inserted in some other day cell
eg:
if i insert date in 23/2
the data inserted in 
19/3

```
    private DataSet GetData()
        {

        string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionCommon"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("PrcScheduler", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ad.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
           return ds;
        }
        //code to insert the data in table
        protected void Btn_AddTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionCommon"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("prcinsertscheduler", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Schedule_title", txtTitle.Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Schedule_Date", hdnSelectedDate.Value);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            txtTitle.Text = "";

        }
        //dayrender event
        protected void calendar12_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = GetData();
            string link = "<a href=' Calendar.aspx?Schedule_ID=";
            string s = e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString();
            e.Cell.Text = e.Day.Date.Day.ToString() + "<BR>";
            LiteralControl l = new LiteralControl();
            l.Text = e.Day.Date.Day.ToString() + "<BR>";
            e.Cell.Controls.Add(l);
      //retriving the data in calenar cel
            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                string scheduledDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Schedule_Date"]).ToShortDateString();

                if (scheduledDate.Equals(s))
                {
                    LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
                    lb.Text = link + (int)row["Schedule_ID"] + "'>" + row["Schedule_title"] as String + "</a>" + "<BR>";
                    e.Cell.Controls.Add(lb);
                }
            }


            HtmlAnchor anchor = new HtmlAnchor();
            anchor.InnerHtml = "Add";
            string method = "ShowAddTaskPane(event,'" + e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString() + "')";
            anchor.HRef = "#";
            anchor.Attributes.Add("onclick", method);

            //To add the htmlanchor in the panel and show that on mouseover
            Panel p1 = new Panel();
            p1.ID = "p" + e.Day.DayNumberText + e.Day.Date.Month.ToString(); ;
            p1.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none;");
            p1.Controls.Add(anchor); ;
            e.Cell.Controls.Add(p1);
            e.Cell.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "ShowInfo('" + p1.ClientID + "')");
            e.Cell.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "HideInfo('" + p1.ClientID + "')");
        }

        protected void btncancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calendar12.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

.aspx

```
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowAddTaskPane(e, selectedDate) {
            debugger;
            var ev = e || window.event;

            document.getElementById("AddTaskPane").style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById("AddTaskPane").style.top = ev.clientY;
            document.getElementById("AddTaskPane").style.left = ev.clientX;

        }

        //    function trimByWord(sentence) {
        //    var result = sentence;
        //    var resultArray = result.split(” “);
        //    if(resultArray.length > 10){
        //    resultArray = resultArray.slice(0, 10);
        //    result = resultArray.join(” “) + “…”;
        //    }
        //return result;
        //}

        function ShowInfo(id) {
            var div = document.getElementById(id);
            document.getElementById("hdnSelectedDate").value = div.innerHTML.match(/'([^']+)'/)[1];

            div.style.display = "block";
        }
        function HideInfo(id) {
            var div = document.getElementById(id);
            div.style.display = "none";
        }


    </script>    

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" />

                </td>

       </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="Btn_AddTask" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="44px" OnClick="Btn_AddTask_Click" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btncancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" 
                        onclick="btncancel_Click" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnoption" runat="server" Text="Option" />

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Calendar ID="calendar12" runat="server" ondayrender="calendar12_DayRender" 
            BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" CellSpacing="1" 
            Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="291px" 
            NextPrevFormat="ShortMonth" Width="416px">
            <DayHeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#333333" 
                Height="8pt" />
            <DayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <NextPrevStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="White" />
            <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
            <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#333399" ForeColor="White" />
            <TitleStyle BackColor="#333399" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Bold="True" 
                Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="White" Height="12pt" />
            <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:Calendar>
          <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSelectedDate" runat="server" /> 
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
      </div>
    </form>
</body>
</ht
```

Comment: please help with the edit option also

Comment: Use convert.ToDate() or DateTime.TryParse() to convert hdnSelectedDate to proper date format before adding it your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with date formatting. Your `hdnSelectedDate.Value` is a text and needs to be in proper format. Its input is generated by `ShowInfo` and you need to make sure that both the input is correct and the `Value` is converted to a valid date representation.